# How to get referer without full URL

Tags: php

how to change this full URL `(wp_get_referer() == (admin_url('/post.php?post=12800&action=edit')))`
to something like this:
`(wp_get_referer() == (admin_url()))`?
I tried to change it to `(wp_get_referer() == (admin_url()))` but referer doesn't work.

Comment: Did you log / dump what each function gives as a Value? Were these the values you expected?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you just want to check if the last page someone visited was an admin page, correct?

If so, you can do the following:

```
if ( strpos( wp_get_referer(), get_site_url() . '/wp-admin/' ) === 0) {
   echo 'Yes, last page was an admin page';
}
```

Comment: @Ridwan Don't edit your question after you received an answer, please. Doing so would invalidate the answer. I rolled back to the previous version.

Comment: @Ridwan, I've seen your edit but my answer still stands. Have you tried using the snippet in my answer or are you just assuming it doesn't work?

Comment: the code is work like a charm and thank you, I edited the question only to make it clear for everyone so they can also get your solution. I realize when you said "If I understand your question" that my question isn't clear enough and it hard to understand.
Thank you very much you safe my life.